# [HTTP]how to change "www.example.com" to "localhost:3000"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, cucumber

hi I'm create test use cucumber in my rails apps. in my step scenario I used http basic authenticate, so far it pass the basic authenticate, but when I wanna to call method on controller and post some params, I had problem :

first I use this code in step but failed not cross to method on controller :

```
post some_admin_url, @params
```

second I used this code, and failed also, the error is when running the URI.parse redirect to "www.example.com" I want to go "localhost:3000/admin", so I can match the data :

```
Net::HTTP.post_form(URI.parse(some_admin_url), {'from' => '2005-01-01','to' => '2005-03-31'}) { |i|  }
```

FUTURE :

@selenium
  Scenario: Admin want to activate user
    Given one user logged in as admin
    And admin page

STEPS :

Given /^one user logged in as admin$/ do
    create_user_admin
    visit '/user_sessions/new'
    fill_in 'user_session[login]', :with=>'siadmin'
    fill_in 'user_session[password]', :with=>'12345'
    click_button 'Anmelden'
  end

Given /^admin page$/ do
    require "net/http"
    require "uri"

```
uri = URI.parse(user_action_admin_users_url)<br/>
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)<br/>
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri)<br/>
request.basic_auth("username", "password")<br/>
response = http.request(request)<br/>
```

end

```
enter code here
```

HELP !!!

THANKS

Answer (score 2):

fl00r's answer probably works, but wouldn't catch redirects.
If you want to catch redirects you have to change this in a higher level. For some test frameworks there is a way to set the default host.

Using Capybara we did that:

`Capybara.default_host = "subdomain.yourapp.local"`

Now we actually use a Rack middleware (in test env only :), that changes changes the env[HTTP_HOST] transparently for the application, so we don't have to care about which testframework / browser driver we use.

What framework do you use?

Comment: I used "rails". I tried to setup Capybara.default_host = "subdomain.yourapp.local" ini test environment, but still does'nt work ?

Comment: We know you use Rails. But the TESTING environment is important. You say you use Cucumber. Can you post the feature and the step definitions you use to run it? Below cucumber you can use differnet test frameworks to do the actual tests. That is important to know. Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: oh.. sorry, selenium maybe that u mean, above I put the future and step

Comment: Abah: OK selenium. But why are you doing all the Net::HTTP stuff? What are you trying to do? You probably want to call a certain url? But why don't you use selenium for that ( visit(your_url_here)) instead of Net::HTTP. You're doing the authentication twice, and loose all the session info that you gained by logging in using selenium. Please read up on basics about Selenium / Cucumber and how user level testing works. For solving your problem with the redirect I think you have to add another piece of rack middleware that rewrites that saves/restores the env[HTTP_HOST] for every request.

Answer (score 0):

```
uname="myapp"
Capybara.default_host = "http://#{uname}.mywebsite.com:3000"
Capybara.server_port = 3000 # could be any of your choice
Capybara.app_host = "http://#{uname}.mywebsite.com:#{Capybara.server_port}"
```

OR

```
request.host="www.myapp.com"
```

,when you are extending ActionController::TestCase

Answer (score -1):

try to change `url` to `path`

```
post some_admin_path, @params
```

or

```
post "http://localhost:3000/#{some_admin_url}", @params
```

Comment: `path` use the same `www.example.com` so it won't work. Also, using `http://localhost:3000` as a constant in your test is a bad idea. You never know if all your team use the port 3000, or if they use docker (and need another IP than localhost). Rails / test frameworks ships with ways to change this. Let's avoid these hacks.